# Reading Physical address value

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

Playing around with Meltdown/Spectre.

Have this small program:

pass.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   char buf[7];

   printf("Password : ");
   fgets(buf, 7, stdin);
   sscanf(buf, "%s", buf);
   printf("addr %p\n",buf);
   while(1)
   {
   }
   printf("Password : %s\n",buf);
   return 0;
}
```

Want to read the physically mapped address value from memory.

```
./pass 
Password : secret
addr 0x7ffc9098b780
```

Found this program that get the physical address from virtual one from userspace:

https://github.com/dwks/pagemap

Output:

```
./pagemap2 18135
=== Maps for pid 18135
0x400000           : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 1 swapped 0 present 1 library /home/user/spectre-meltdown-poc/pass
0x600000           : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library /home/user/spectre-meltdown-poc/pass
0x601000           : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library /home/user/spectre-meltdown-poc/pass
0x206a000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library [heap]
0x206b000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x206c000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x206d000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x206e000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x206f000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2070000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2071000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2072000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2073000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2074000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2075000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2076000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2077000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2078000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2079000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207a000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207b000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207c000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207d000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207e000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x207f000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2080000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2081000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2082000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2083000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2084000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2085000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2086000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2087000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2088000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x2089000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x208a000          : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [heap]
0x7f27b2365000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 1 swapped 0 present 1 library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
0x7f27b253d000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7f27b253e000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7f27b253f000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7f27b2563000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7f27b2564000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7f27b2565000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
0x7f27b2566000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
0x7f27b2567000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library 
0x7ffe2498c000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2498d000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2498e000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2498f000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24990000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24991000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24992000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24993000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24994000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24995000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24996000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24997000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24998000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe24999000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499a000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499b000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499c000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499d000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499e000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe2499f000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a0000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a1000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a2000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a3000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a4000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a5000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a6000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a7000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a8000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249a9000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library [stack]
0x7ffe249aa000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library [stack]
0x7ffe249ab000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 0 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [stack]
0x7ffe249ac000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 1 library [stack]
0x7ffe249ca000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [vvar]
0x7ffe249cb000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [vvar]
0x7ffe249cc000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 1 swapped 0 present 1 library [vdso]
0x7ffe249cd000     : pfn 0                soft-dirty 1 file/shared 0 swapped 0 present 0 library [vdso]
```

Where will be my "secret" string located? on the stack? Which physical address should I try?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you misunderstood something about Meltdown / Spectre. It doesn't matter, because it's your application's secret. Meltdown / Spectre is about finding secrets of some other program or the kernel.

Comment: Well I thought since the secret is in memory (virtual memory of the process) meltdown will allow me to read it from but I need to know the physical adress of that virtual adress. I assumed the secret is run as one user and i exploit meltdown as other user

Comment: I have Meltdown Proof of Cocept where as I understand I need to provide Physical Address to read from. Hence my question, how to figure out physical address from virtual one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Linux debugger like WinDbg for Windows. A similar debugger should exist for Linux, too, possibly it's [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb).

The user mode part:

```
0:002> !heap -s
SEGMENT HEAP ERROR: failed to initialize the extention
LFH Key                   : 0x0000002452efc0db
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000000400000 00000002    2048   1104   2048    690     6     2    0      0   LFH

0:002> dd 400000
00000000`00400000  00000000 00000000 8d12536f 01001481
00000000`00400010  ffeeffee 00000000 040c0018 00000000
00000000`00400020  00400128 00000000 00400000 00000000
00000000`00400030  00400000 00000000 00000100 00000000
00000000`00400040  00400a80 00000000 00500000 00000000
00000000`00400050  00000042 00000001 00000000 00000000
00000000`00400060  004bdfe0 00000000 004bdfe0 00000000
00000000`00400070  00000002 00000000 00000000 00100000
```

The kernel mode part:

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 notepad.exe    
PROCESS fffffa801d440640
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0fec    Peb: 7fffffdb000  ParentCid: 0dec
    DirBase: 4e7480000  ObjectTable: fffff8a008f3ddd0  HandleCount:  66.
    Image: notepad.exe

0: kd> .process  fffffa801d440640
Implicit process is now fffffa80`1d440640

0: kd> !vtop 0 400000
Amd64VtoP: Virt 00000000`00400000, pagedir 00000004`e7480000
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 00000004`e7480000
Amd64VtoP: PDPE 00000006`4519b000
Amd64VtoP: PDE 00000006`4521e010
Amd64VtoP: PTE 00000006`51db9000
Amd64VtoP: Mapped phys 00000006`45c3a000
Virtual address 400000 translates to physical address 645c3a000.

0: kd> !dd 645c3a000
#645c3a000 00000000 00000000 8d12536f 01001481
#645c3a010 ffeeffee 00000000 040c0018 00000000
#645c3a020 00400128 00000000 00400000 00000000
#645c3a030 00400000 00000000 00000100 00000000
#645c3a040 00400a80 00000000 00500000 00000000
#645c3a050 00000042 00000001 00000000 00000000
#645c3a060 004bdfe0 00000000 004bdfe0 00000000
#645c3a070 00000002 00000000 00000000 00100000
```

As you can see, the values in virtual user mode address `00000000'00400000` are identical to those of the physical address `645c3a000`. You found the correct physical address and you can do with it whatever you like.

Comment: Great answer. Seems easy in WinDbg! I think in GDB you can only work with virtual addresses. Will try to find it out under Linux (with using /proc/PID/pagemap). Will add comment how it will go.

Comment: @android_dev: if you know it, you can also post your own answer end even accept that answer as the correct one.

Comment: Found a tool called pagemap that does this. https://github.com/dwks/pagemap